# Help identifying thermostatic mixer (shower temperature control)

Tags: plumbing, shower, valve

I have the following valve in my shower.

[image]

I thought it was a Grohe, but after contacting their support - it seems it is not.

There is something wrong with the valve, not letting us decrease the temperature.

I need to disassemble the unit to find the problem. However, I can't figure out how to get the thing apart. Many units have a small allen key on the underside, this one does not. It was purchased in 2002, in Canada.

I have already tried removing the wall plate, but it was blocked by the knob for complete removal, and clearly the knob needs to come off in some way.

If someone can identify the unit, that would help me find the manual.
Alternatively general advice on disassembling these types of things.

---

Edit after 10yrs.. Kudos to [Wes M.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/34001/wes-m) who provide instructions on how to actually open it up. The 'cap' at the end rotates left with a bit of force and unscrews. The raised ring also rotates left to unscrew and is like a big threaded washer.

I tagged Neil's answer as the correct one, as it is indeed aquabrass. The fine folk at https://www.ad-waters.com/contact/ appear to support this product still and I'm in touch with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's aquabrass I used to work at taps and it's there brand or a Candian  company it can either be half inch or 3/4

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 2):

After shutting off the water, try adjusting the knob to the open position to see if there's a hidden screw.  Otherwise, there may be a cap that just pops off with the right pressure and often with the careful use of a blade (I usually try with a putty knife first before moving down to sharper tools).

Answer (score 0):

I have one of these and just opened it up.

Rotate the knob to the left until the heat stopper stops it. Then turn the knob cap (or the closest part to you) to the left and it should unscrew.  From that point you can unscrew the grip washer and then pull the plate off (once you've unscrewed the 2 bolts on it) by depressing the heat stopper as you pull it out.

Now I just need to figure out how to adjust the hot cold temps . . .